# Neovim deleting lines on write

Tags: neovim, save

Something really odd is happening randomly when I save changes to a file in Neovim.
Often if I press <kbd>esc</kbd>`:w`<kbd>Enter</kbd> quickly, hundreds of lines are deleted from the end of the file. So far I have only seen this happen when editing Markdown files. I have also never seen this happen if I type that key sequence slowly. Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: Strange. Have you tried going through your history after it happened? Might be a creative typo in `:w` that causes this. Did you create a `:W` by any chance?